# What is the meaning of Pageset?

Tags: php, javascript, html

It might seem silly to ask but I couldn't find a concrete solution on internet. What is the meaning of Pageset. When someone says, include the code in Pageset, what are they referring to?

Comment: This is not a fixed term that I've ever heard in neither of the technologies you mention. It could really be anything - I know CMS's that use the term, but each refers to a different thing. You'll need to ask the person who said it to get clarity.

Comment: Can you give more detail about the code itself, or what context 'pageset' was mentioned in?  That's not a term I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A set of Pages used for application execution control. A PageSet
>   manages, stores, matches and executes Pages.

That is all I could find on the term. Basically say if say you have a blog, you can have a pageset for modifying the entries, as in add, edit, delete. Each of those actions will have a different page and control(s) to run that action. A pageset would be the group of those.